# Find out source of installed gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems

This is probably simple, but I'm stumped...

So I've got a gem that needs a fix already installed on a shared development machine.  **How do I tell where it came from, so I can fork it?**

Just to eliminate some obvious things, it definitely is installed:

```
$ be gem list spp_manifests

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

spp_manifests (0.0.4)
```

Checking the gemspec reveals nothing of use (except the author's name, but he's away):

```
$ gem specification spp_manifests

name: spp_manifests
homepage: ""
rubyforge_project:
```

But it's not public in Github, it's not in our company Github repo, it's not in Rubygems and googling for the name produces lots of links to the Singapore People's Party election manifestos but nothing of use.

Comment: You can run `gem unpack spp_manifests` to dump the gem's files into the current directory. Then you can poke around for clues in the files or simply start fixing bugs

Comment: You should find the remote URL in your `Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So short answer is, once gemmed up, the code is completely split off from the repo it once lived in and there's no way to find out the address of that original repo.

However, it is possible to:

a) unpack the gem's code, so you can create a new repo for it (credit to Flambino)

```
gem unpack spp_manifests
```

b) find out where the gem was downloaded from (credit to Stefan)

```
more Gemfile.lock

GEM
  remote: http://gems.megacorp.com/
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this out now since i use a proxy but you could do a gem update spp_manifest while in a console window on the same machine you issue a "netstat -b 1" (or the nix counterpart) to list all your connections. Your machine schould make a connection to the source and do an install if a more recent version is found.
In the list of connections you should see the source.

You can also chek with "gem environment" the remote sources or a remote lookup wih "gem query -r -n spp_manifests"

Comment: Your first method could tell me which server the gem was downloaded from, although checking Gemfile.lock would be easier.  2nd and 3rd provide nothing useful.